# grails -xlint error prevents running a project

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I'm working on a big grails project, that has tons of plugins contributions from different parts of company. I moved to new PC (mac one) and now can' solve issue i having.

Project uses grails 2.0.0, groovy 1.8.6 and java 1.6.0_32. Then i do grails run-app in the project directory (from my terminal), i receive this error:

```
| Compiling 11 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Invalid commandline usage for javac.
javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:-options
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                        Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                   Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}    Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                   Generate no warnings
  -verbose                  Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation              Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>         Specify where to find user class files
  -sourcepath <path>        Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>     Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>           Override location of installed extensions
  -d <directory>            Specify where to place generated class files
  -encoding <encoding>      Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>         Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>         Generate class files for specific VM version
  -help                     Print a synopsis of standard options



1 error
```

i tried everything that came in to my mind - changed java, upgrade grails, searched project source for customised -xlint arguments. Nothing like that helped...

Maybe anyone can give some tip to resolve this? It works for other guys in project, but both of us - can't make this project working after PC upgrade.

Comment: Does the latest Grails version exhibit the same problem? I found a [jira issue here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8449) which says it's unreproducible with 2.0.3

Comment: I ran into something similar for a project, and the solution was to upgrade from 2.0.0 to 2.0.4.  However, that upgrade also opened up a can of worms with integration testing due to a bug in the class processing.

Comment: In our case upgrading to grails 2.0.4 didn't help at all. Same issue appears.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think

```
-Xlint:-options
```

Is a valid java parameter: you'll need to locate where in your grails/java scripts/environment variables this typo has been made and correct it.

See the following for proper Xlint arguments, if you did indeed intend to use it (I suspect you did not, and would be best off leaving it out all together)
http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/10/javacs-xlint-options.html